# CKAN server error

Tags: ckan

From time to time I am getting a timeout error from my CKAN server. The log file shows the following error message:

TimeoutError: QueuePool  limit of size 5 overflow 10 reached.

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

PK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QueuePool I think refers to the database connections limit. Are you not closing connections in an extension or getting a very large amount of traffic?

Comment: I am not sure if I should be closing any connection since I do not create any connection. I am using the CKAN API actions to do any kind of CRUD operations. I assume the API handles creation and closing of DB connections. The only thing that I can guess that might be causing this problem is that I have a background (a separate thread) scheduler that does some CRUD type actions on the database. I am guessing for the background task I may have to create DB session and close it when the background task is done.

Comment: I added the following line prior to calling the background job:  session = meta.Session #ckan.model.meta and then after background function call, added this line: session.remove() #and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is CKAN's SQLAlchemy running out of connections to the database.
You'll see it with when apache sees several simultaneous requests
under a bit of load. You can replicate it using something like 'ab' to
provide the simultaneous load.

The SQLAlchemy pool of connections is shared amongst threads in the
same CKAN process, but each CKAN process has its own pool.

You could increase the numbers of connections in the pool, but
remember that postgres has a limit of 100 connections by default. So
with multiple processes you'll hit a limit reasonably quickly. Or you
can limit the number of CKAN processess. I believe Ian noted a few
days ago one CKAN dependency that is not thread-safe, so best stick to
just processes for now.

If using Apache, you could run the mod_wsgi in daemon mode and specify
limits for the processes/threads. If you're on nginx/uwsgi then this
is naturally limits the number of processes, which is better.

The best solution would be to use a separate app to hold the
connection pool. That has the advantage of working across CKAN
threads. PGPool is an option, but we went for pgbouncer, which I
believe is faster and we've been very pleased with it.